# pelican: do not build specific article

Tags: python, blogs, pelican

what's the best way to not build a page for a specific Pelican article?

I'm asking because I'm using some article pages mainly as metadata collections but I don't want them to have a specific page you can access.
For example I have a bunch of articles for portfolio clients which include metadata like the link to their logo, name of the client, the category of the job we did, etc... but there's not actual article I want to link to.

I tried to give them the Draft metadata or Hidden metadata but that way they do not show up when I iterate them in the relevant page.
I would like to be able to iterate them and access and use their metadata without building a webpage for them.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me what you're after, it sounds like what you really want is to be able to include data from a file into other articles?

If so, you could use the reStructuredText [include](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#including-an-external-document-fragment) directive. Save the metadata files with an extension that won't be picked up by Pelican and then include them in all the pages where you want to use them.